# How to use downloaded yarn dependencies

Tags: html, css, node.js, package-managers, yarnpkg

this is probably a **really** stupid question, but it'd be awesome if you could help me. 
Here's the problem: I've added [a package](https://yarn.fyi/semantic-ui-css) to my project. It contains some css files which I want to use in my HTML files and so on. I've added it by using `yarn add <package>`. The files are located inside `/node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css`.

Do I have to reference complete node_module path to load the css file inside my HTML file? That just doesn't sound right. Before I used a package manager I just downloaded a few css files, placed them into `/vendor/css/` and used them.

Or is it normal these days to use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css">`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target folders can be [defined](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install#toc-yarn-install-modules-folder) with

```
yarn install --modules-folder vendor/ semantic-ui-css
```

giving you a results of

```
href="vendor/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css"
```

Each package will always be wrapped in its own folder.